# Seq with maximal elements

Tags: scala, mapping

I have a Seq and function Int => Int. What I need to achieve is to take from original Seq only thoose elements that would be equal to the maximum of the resulting sequence (the one, I'll have after applying given function):

```
def mapper:Int=>Int= x=>x*x
val s= Seq( -2,-2,2,2 )
val themax= s.map(mapper).max
s.filter( mapper(_)==themax)
```

But this seems wasteful, since it has to map twice (once for the filter, other for the maximum).
Is there a better way to do this? (without using a cycle, hopefully)

**EDIT**
The code has since been edited; in the original this was the filter line: `s.filter( mapper(_)==s.map(mapper).max)`. As [om-nom-nom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/298389) has pointed out, this evaluates `s.map(mapper).max each (filter) iteration, leading to quadratic complexity.

Comment: It is unclear of what exactly you are trying to do above.

Comment: There is a thing that is much more wasteful that double traversing: you're calling max over the s.map(mapper) and max is a O(n). So you'll end up with quadratic complexity.

Comment: @om-nom-nom Yes, I was wondering about that, so I edited a while back. I'll put the max in a val

Comment: @Jatin This is highly simplified code, since I'm dealing with complex structures on the original; I'm not sure how I can further simplify it. If it makes this clearer, in the original this is not a Seq of Int, but of objects. All I want do is get the maximal elements (after applying that function).

Comment: @scala_newbie it is now clear :). I was asking about the previous code, where you had max inside the filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that does the mapping only once and using the `foldLeft' function:

The principle is to go through the seq and for each mapped element if it is greater than all mapped before then begin a new sequence with it, otherwise if it is equal return the list of all maximums and the new mapped max. Finally if it is less then return the previously computed Seq of maximums.

```
def getMaxElems1(s:Seq[Int])(mapper:Int=>Int):Seq[Int] = s.foldLeft(Seq[(Int,Int)]())((res, elem) => {
  val e2 = mapper(elem)
  if(res.isEmpty || e2>res.head._2) 
    Seq((elem,e2)) 
  else if (e2==res.head._2) 
    res++Seq((elem,e2)) 
  else res 
}).map(_._1) // keep only original elements

// test with your list
scala> getMaxElems1(s)(mapper)
res14: Seq[Int] = List(-2, -2, 2, 2)

//test with a list containing also non maximal elements
scala> getMaxElems1(Seq(-1, 2,0, -2, 1,-2))(mapper)
res15: Seq[Int] = List(2, -2, -2)
```

**Remark:** About complexity

The algorithm I present above has a complexity of O(N) for a list with N elements. However:

- the operation of mapping all elements is of complexity O(N)
- the operation of computing the max is of complexity O(N)
- the operation of zipping is of complexity O(N)
- the operation of filtering the list according to the max is also of complexity O(N)
- the operation of mapping all elements is of complexity O(M), with M the number of final elements

So, finally the algorithm you presented in your question has the same complexity (quality) than my answer's one, moreover the solution you present is more clear than mine. So, even if the 'foldLeft' is more powerful, for this operation I would recommend your idea, but with zipping original list and computing the map only once (especially if your map is more complicated than a simple square). Here is the solution computed with the help of  *scala_newbie* in question/chat/comments.

```
def getMaxElems2(s:Seq[Int])(mapper:Int=>Int):Seq[Int] = {
  val mappedS = s.map(mapper) //map done only once 
  val m = mappedS.max         // find the max
  s.zip(mappedS).filter(_._2==themax).unzip._1
}

// test with your list
scala> getMaxElems2(s)(mapper)
res16: Seq[Int] = List(-2, -2, 2, 2)

//test with a list containing also non maximal elements
scala> getMaxElems2(Seq(-1, 2,0, -2, 1,-2))(mapper)
res17: Seq[Int] = List(2, -2, -2)
```

Comment: That's clever :O. Note I'm trying to get the **original** elements, not the mapped ones, but I guess one could keep the originals in that Seq and return the maximum on a separate argument, right?

Comment: See edited code, I still prefer the second solution, even if it now tends to be more complicated than the first one.

Comment: Also, about the complexity, fortunately my map is O(1). My original idea was to map once, get the maximum, then get the *indexes* where the condition evaluates to True, and get only the elements on those indexes (which is how you'd do it in MATLAB, or python-numpy),  but I couldn't find a method for that (I guess one could write a for...)

Comment: In functional programming the `zip` is usually preferred to the indices.

Comment: I don't know enough about scala to be able to make that second solution return the original elements instead of the mapped ones. About `zip`, indeed, I guess zipping the original elements with the mapped ones would work even better!

Comment: Well, in my REPL 'res' contains the original elements.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong then, I've printed the outputs and it returns the mapped ones. My code is [pasted here](https://gist.github.com/4141197)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20041/discussion-between-chrisjamesc-and-scala-newbie)

Comment: @ziggystar Thanks for the suggestion. I edited my code considering this and the solution proposed by scala_newbie in the chat.